DEM DTC aging depends on the DTC status mask
when will aging counter of the dtc will starts reducing, specifically based on Which bit of the status mask aging counter will depends.
does it depends on the Bit0: Test failed or Bit1 test failed in this operation cycle

Please follow the guide to adjust your question. Right now it does not contain any code neither enough information to specify the problem.

The aging process is described in AUTOSAR_SWS_DiagnosticEventManager chapter 7.7.8 "Aging of diagnostic events".
It depends in the TFTOC, TNCTOC, CDTC and PDTC status bits, and an aging counter assigned to the event (usually the IGCYC).
